# Array access 5.2 != 5.3

Tags: php, arrays

I have a piece of code:

```
$data = array();

$data['foo'] = 'tst';
$data['bar'] = array('asd');
$data['user'] = new stdClass();

var_dump(isset($data->foo));
```

Now i have executed the code on two environments.

First:

```
PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny16 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2012 08:19:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethan
```

Second:

```
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.24 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr  4 2014 02:25:37) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

On the first i got as result `bool(true)` but on the second `bool(false)`.
I've read the migration guide (php.net), but there was nothing to find about this behavior.

Can anyone explain me this behavior?

Note:

If i change the code to

```
var_dump(isset($data['foo']))
```

i get the same result on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://3v4l.org/CcU3X), the behaviour changed between 5.2.11 and 5.2.12. The [release notes for 5.2.12](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.2.12) refer to [bug #50255 `isset() and empty() silently casts array to object`](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50255) having been fixed.

So, it was a bug in older versions.